# characteristic function of rationals not the difference of two increasing functions

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that on a non-trivial interval of $\mathbb R$ the characteristic function of rationals($1$ if the number is a rational, $0$ otherwise) is not the difference of two increasing functions.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Any monotone function is continuous with the possible exception of countably many points.

Comment: This is easier than mine ... I was going to say something about the first Baire class.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $1_{\Bbb Q}(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$where $f,g$ are non-decreasing. Pick an integer $k$ and numbers 
$$a<x_1<y_1<x_2<y_2<\ldots <x_k<y_k<b$$
with $1_{\Bbb Q}(x_i)=1$, $1_{\Bbb Q}(y_i)=0$.
Then 
$$f(y_i)-f(y_{i-1})\ge f(y_i)-f(x_i)\ge f(y_i)-g(y_i)-f(x_i)+g(x_i)=1  $$
and 
$$\begin{align}f(b)-f(a)&\ge f(y_k)-f(y_1)\\
&=f(y_k)-f(y_{k-1})+f(y_{k-1})-f(y_{k-2})+\ldots +f(y_2)-f(y_1)\\
&\ge k-1\end{align} $$
contradiction if $k$ is big enough